# How to find reverse dependencies on npm package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to find out which packages depend on `express` among the installed `sails/kraken/loopback/hapi/koa` etc. Are there `npm` sub-commands or other ways to locally list all reverse dependencies on one specific npm package?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Adding package name after `npm ls` will show you tree only with the specified package.

```
npm ls express
```

Comment: Thanks.  The command `npm view express dependencies` shows only direct dependencies, but i can't figure out how to view its complete dependencies tree.

Comment: only works if you have the module installed into a node_modules folder... doesn't do you any good if you're trying to resolve a dry run.

Comment: For dev dependencies, use `npm ls --dev express`

Comment: For scoped packages (which begin with @), using only the scope `@date-io` fails with `EINVALIDTAGNAME` error. Instead use the complete package name like `npm ls @date-io/date-fns`

Answer (score 79):

I specifically wanted to find what package used a dependency that was breaking an initial install. This may help somebody out trying todo the same:

`find ./node_modules/ -name package.json | xargs grep <the_package_name>`

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: wow, finally a nice solution! I'd also add that `find ./node_modules -name package.json | xargs grep -e 'PACKAGE_NAME": "'` helps get rid of other mentions of the PACKAGE_NAME and focuses on instances where it is used with a version number..

Comment: and also good to mention is that this method can be used recursively to find what first level dependency ends up importing the specified package..

Comment: what is the alternative command for Windows Powershell?

Answer (score 5):

In case someone is using pnpm, this should help to find packages that depend on lodash for example:

`pnpm list --depth 1 | grep --color -E '(^\w|\slodash)'`