# How to determine path to deep outdated/deprecated packages (NPM)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

How to determine, which packages (**deep**-dependencies, not top-level) are outdated in the local `node_modules` folder?

I run the following command:

```
npm install
```

having this in my `package.json`:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.3.4",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "hbs": "~4.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.6.1",
    "mkdirp-bluebird": "^1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "opener": "^1.4.1",
    "sequelize": "^3.19.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.1"
},
```

and get the following output:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
```

In my `package.json` all packages are fresh. But some of the **deep dependencies** are outdated and I don't know how to determine **WHICH**, I neither know which of explicitly installed packages caused that... *Bonus*: if I can do it quickly;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find reverse dependencies on npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923195/how-to-find-reverse-dependencies-on-npm-package)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim nope, because it is about building a list of dependencies of dependencies. I wanted to find _deep outdated deps_ , and maybe, a way to upgrade them. And there are good answers here, which help ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you want ...

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

then to show available updates

```
ncu
```

also ...

```
ncu -u
```

which actually change `package.json` to reflect the output of `ncu`.

And if that wasn't enough ...

```
ncu -m bower
```

check for new bower packages too!

Package `npm-check-updates` and more documentation [**is here**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

### Edit for DEEP dependencies

`npm-check-updates` does not provide a depth option. With further research I found that npm [now provides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated) a CLI utitility to do what you want.

This essentially allows you to do ...

```
npm outdated --depth=5
```

which provides a similar output to `npm-check-updates` **but** also checks depth.

Note the default depth is 0 viz top level packages only. Also note that `npm outdated` only lists

- current version
- wanted version
- latest version

it does not actually do the update.

To update packages use:

```
npm update --depth=5
```

*npm warns against using the depth option in conjunction with [npm-update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)*

Comment: `npm outdated --depth=5` with `npm update` -- my choice!!

Thank you;)

Comment: recently i have found that ncu only works as expected if you delete the node_modules folder first before using it! weird i know

Comment: And now I prefer to use `npm-check`, but `ncu` is good enough!

Comment: `ncu` command ask me to see https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates/issues/136#issuecomment-155721102

Comment: Ironic how I get `npm WARN deprecated` messages when I install npm-check-updates :)

Answer (score 1):

Another one option (I found it later) — [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) (thanks [Hannah Wolfe](https://hannah.wf/npm-maintenance/#npmcheck))

Install:

```
npm install npm-check --global
```

Check and update dependencies for the current project:

```
npm-check -u
```