# Upgrade a specific dependency

Tags: npm

I am getting a message:

```
Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
```

when I do 'npm update'. This question doesn't have anything to do with `Chokidar`. I mainly want to know how to update an arbitrary dependency when that dependency isn't specifically listed in the package.json. How is this done? And how do I tell which modules/dependencies are affected by this upgrade?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923195/how-to-find-reverse-dependencies-on-npm-package will show which package depends on the package you specify.

Comment: So if I don't know which of the dependencies depend on say 'Chokidar' I am out of luck and have to run through the dependencies one by one to see which of the dependencies in package.json directly or indirectly depend on it.

Comment: Er, with the first answer, `npm ls chokidar` would show you what are the packages depending directly and indirectly on chokidar.

Comment: Since chokidar is not in package.json 'npm ls chokidar' shows `-- (empty)